# Smallest possible Vuetify CSS/JS size 0.5Mb?

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I created a brand new NUXT app and included in it the following minimum setup:

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "analyze": "nuxt build --analyze"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^2.11.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  buildModules: [["@nuxtjs/vuetify"]]
};
```

```html
<!-- pages/about.vue -->
<template>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</template>
```

Note that I am not actually USING any of the Vuetify components. So if I run `npm generate`, what do I get?

```
./dist/about.index.html  --- 243KB, almost all of it vuetify CSS
./_nuxt/'vendors.app' --- 266KB, 265KB of it Vuetify
```

Contrast this with what happens when I make a single change  to the above setup: I simply delete the entire nuxt.config.js file, falling back to the default file. After running `npm generate`, I get:

```
./dist/about.index.html  --- 2KB
./_nuxt/'vendors.app' --- 0KB, The file is gone!
```

What happened to the tree shaking of Vuetify? (I tried forcing treeshaking by setting it to true in nuxt.config.js, and no change) Is 250KB of vendors.app and 250KB of CSS the minimum you have to 'pay' in order to use Vuetify? Or am I making some kind of mistake in this setup?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I was hoping to build out a SSR Vuetify site, but need it to be as light as possible.

Comment: Nope. Still hoping that someone will answer this. Well, not really hoping anymore.

Comment: Same issue ans unable to resolve it after trying every idea I've found. My hopes are on Nuxt 3 and Vuetify 3 releases...

Comment: Check out Vite SSR as a Nuxt alternative.

Comment: There is a way to disable vuetify utility class, check here: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/issues/84#issuecomment-525244859